# Couchbase Memcached Filter

Tags: java, memcached, couchbase

Is it possible to filter Couchbase Memcached documents?

It doesn't have to be a sophisticated filter like we do in Couchbase bucket types, it can be as simple as startKey and endKey filter.

Comment: Since it is not supported in the Memcached Bucket (that supports the same features than plain memcached), do you think you can use a Couchbase bucket with a view? (to be able to do such queries/filter)

Comment: @TugGrall Cause I don't really need to persist some of the documents on the server, it wouldn't be very ideal for me to do such thing. Another idea would be to use temporary data with expiry date using Couchbase bucket types, but tbh I don't know if this is a good move or not.

Answer (score 0):

The memcached bucket in Couchbase is meant to be plain old memcached so it is not possible to run queries or do any filtering on the server side.